# Replacement for Windows Movie Maker

Tags: windows, video-editing

Does anyone know of a nice replacement of Windows Movie Maker. That is, a video editor that is easy to use, and still pretty capable with effects, adding music, adding photos etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OpenShot](https://www.openshot.org/) does a pretty fine job. I use it for some light editing, but it can handle serious editing, as well.

Comment: That was indeed a great tip, I love it :-)

Comment: I'm glad. I'm running it on Windows and Linux. it Works well on either one.